# What is a t-value that I can use for running the student's t-test on related samples?

Tags: st.statistics

I want to use the t-test on samples grabbed from performing a procedure in three slightly different ways.  These are very correlated.  I have gotten several samples of results from all 3 of these.  I've generated their means, standard deviations, confidence intervals, etc.

How do I now run the student's t-test on it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is an example of the wrong way to ask a statistics question! Do not ask "...How do I use the X-test", but describe yout data, your experiment, and the research question you want to solve. maybe then we can fins an answer, and maybe that answer do not inculde an t-test.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you follow to collect the data from the processes that you are observing, define a mathematical model. When you perform a hypothesis test, you are asking questions
about the parameters of the model. A t-test refers to the t-distribution, a statistical
distribution that pops up frequently when asking questions about model parameters.

I would suggest that you pull out your favorite elementary statistics book and read
about one-way analysis of variance, keeping in mind the procedure that must be followed
for this version of an ANOVA to be legitimate.

Answer (score -1):

Since the Hypothesis Testing is being done on different values of the same variable, the technique that is used is paired/dependant t-test.

Here is the formula : (Observed Mean Difference - Expected Mean Difference)/Standard Error

Step 1 : You need to calculate the mean difference between the two variables of all the observations. This is the Observed Mean Difference.
Step 2: If you assume that the Null Hypothesis is true, the Expected Mean Difference is to be taken as 0. 
Step 3: Standard Error is the variation in the standard deviation due to chance. This is calculated by dividing the standard deviation of the population by the sample size.
Step 4: Use these to compute the t-value.

Comment: You gave a partially correct standard paired t-test method covered in any introduction to statistics, but the question is not about that.